# JQuery Select all fields and check for duplicates, respond with message

Tags: jquery, select, click, duplicates

I am trying to create a button that selects all the fields that are queried inside the select. It has to check for duplicates and prompt with a message if there are duplicates allowing the user to select their own fields. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$.get_id_num = function(num){
    var num_str = num.toString();
    var elements = num_str.split('|');
    return elements[0];
}


$.select_all_nbrs = function() {
    $("select[multiple] option").attr('selected', 'selected');
}


 $( '#id_selectall_btn').click( function() {
        var nbr = $.get_id_nbr("#id_nbrs");
            if($("#id_nbrs option[value='nbr']").length == 0){
                show_messages("Duplicate!");
            }else{
                ($.select_all_nbrs("#id_nbrs"));
        }                       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.select_all_nbrs = function(id) {
    $("#"+id+" > option").attr('selected', 'selected');
}


 $( '#id_selectall_btn').click( function() {
        var nbr = $("#id_nbrs");
        var duplicate=false;
        nbr.find("option").each(function(){
            if(nbr.find("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").length >1){
                duplicate=true;
                show_messages("Duplicate! value "+$(this).val());
            }  
        });
        if(!duplicate){
            ($.select_all_nbrs("#id_nbrs"));
        }

});
```

As per comment if you want to select all but duplicates with message try below code

```
$.select_all_nbrs = function(id) {
    var nbr = $("#id_nbrs"); 
    var duplicate=false;
    nbr.find("option").each(function(){
        if(nbr.find("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").length >1){
            duplicate=true;
            show_messages("Duplicate! value "+$(this).val());
        }else{
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }  
    });

}


 $( '#id_selectall_btn').click( function() {

        ($.select_all_nbrs("#id_nbrs"));

});
```

As per comment Op want to compare only first Option for duplicates 
Notice the changed line `if(nbr.find("option[value^='"+$.get_id_num($(this).val())+"|']").length >1){`

`value^=` means value starts with.. 
so condition mean find Options which have value starting with  `$.get_id_num($(this).val())+"|"` if the length greater than 1 means Duplicate. 
we need to add `|` too as `<option value="1|2|3">` is `not duplicate` of  `<option value="11|2|3">` but duplicate of `<option value="1|5|8">`

```
$.select_all_nbrs = function(id) {
    var nbr = $("#id_nbrs"); 
    var duplicate=false;
    nbr.find("option").each(function(){
        if(nbr.find("option[value^='"+$.get_id_num($(this).val())+"|']").length >1){
            duplicate=true;
            show_messages("Duplicate! value "+$(this).val());
        }else{
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }  
    });

}

$.get_id_num = function(num){
    var num_str = num.toString();
    var elements = num_str.split('|');
    return elements[0];
 }
 $( '#id_selectall_btn').click( function() {

        ($.select_all_nbrs("#id_nbrs"));

});
```

Comment: Just to take it one step further, what if I wanted to select everything but not the duplicates? (So if  clicked on the button, it would select all the values but the duplicates and would prompt me with the message. )

Comment: Thanks, that works out well. But I have the var nbr = $("#id_nbrs"); being passed through a function that parses it var nbr = $.get_id_nbr("#id_nbrs"); Now it doesn't work because it is a comparison of the element with the option. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Can you elaborate? which comparison fails?

Comment: I edited the code above to show the other function that parses the string out. So basically I have a string that contains a unique id in element[0]. I want to find any duplicates and have them unselected, while all the other options are selected. Does that help?

Comment: >> I want to find any duplicates and have them unselected 
Its already done in 2nd code in my answer... 

If i understood the get_id_num returns the value of duplicate element... I think that method does not needed anymore.. Or you can show me where you are calling it and with what parameter.

Comment: Ok, so it works ok when the #id_nbrs is passed in. But I don't want to match the entire option, just the first element of that option. That is why I am parsing it out so that I can get the first element and then compare those to each option in the select.

Comment: yep, just the first part (element) of the option string. Thank you by the way. You've been extremely helpful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29938/discussion-between-rahul-maindargi-and-sxkaur)